# Regex vs IsNaN: which is better to use for checking an input is a number

Tags: javascript

To check whether a given input is a number, which of the following approaches is better/comprehensive or efficient?

`!isNaN(input)`

OR using regex,

```
var regex=/^[0-9]+$/;
(x.match(regex))
```

P.S I'm ignoring empty string ("") for now which will return true for `!isNaN("")`

Comment: Are floating point numbers legal? Cause that regex won't find 'em. Nor negative numbers. Nor scientific notation. Nor numbers with extraneous whitespace on either end (which JS ignores when parsing to number). (All of this is a hint that string tests for legal numbers are a bad idea)

Comment: What is holding you back to conduct performance tests?

Comment: What do you mean by "input"? Are these inputs strings? Keep in mind that `isNan("37")` returns `false`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah I think I was looking for that. Thank you.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes true. But then even that regex to operate x needs to be converted to String(x) in case x is a number. So input is a input string.

Comment: If the input is a string, it's obvious that `isNan` is not the right tool for you

Comment: @NicoHaase He is using `!isNaN()` (not `IsNaN()` as you said) and it's working fine for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little impact on performance in both cases unless you want to parse a million strings or so. However here is a little benchmark parsing 1 mio. strings per solution. Could be improved of course. In my case (Chromium on KUbuntu) `!isNaN()` is faster.

```js
let t = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
  let input = String(i);
  let output = !isNaN(input);
}
console.log("!isNaN() took " + (performance.now() - t));

t = performance.now();
let regex=/^[0-9]+$/;
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
  let input = String(i);
  let output = input.match(regex);
}
console.log("match() took " + (performance.now() - t));
```

I want to add that another way is `String(parseInt(input)) == input`.

Comment: `match()` is faster for me - 210 against 271 for `!isNaN()`. Firefox in Mint in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: Well, I was asked this during an interview. Couldn't tell them it's 'rediculous' :) The problem used regex and I was asked if this could be improved. The obvious solution came to my mind was `!isNaN`

Answer (score -1):

if you SIMPLY want to check whether a given input is a number
then i think using 'isNan()' would suffice
it works for both integer numbers as well as decimals.
// emphasis on 'SIMPLY'